# How can I round the corners of the sourceRect for Peek and Pop 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, peek-pop

In Safari, if you use 3D touch, the sourceRect of the link that is being touched has rounded corners. When I set the source rect in: `func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {`on previewingContext, I can only set `previewingContext.sourceRect` which doesn't allow me to round the corners, or set a multi corner area. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can indirectly set round corners to the sourceRect by adding a corner radius to the sourceView's layer. The when you set `previewingContext.sourceRect` to the sourceView's bounds, the area that stays in focus will also have the rounded corners.

Here is an example that uses a pressable UILabel:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing?
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(150, 250, 100, 50))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let background = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        background.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
        view.addSubview(background)

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.text = "Press me!"
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(label)

        previewingContext = registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: label)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        previewingContext.sourceRect = label.bounds

        return UIViewController()
    }

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        showViewController(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @joem, how would one go about implementing this for a `UITableView`, in the sense that I probably shouldn't make an `id< UIViewControllerPreviewing>` for every `UITableViewCell`, but would like to show some rounded views, (eg. like Apple does in the messages app; 3D Touching the avatar)

Answer (score -2):

First of all the sourceView should have a cornerRadius on its layer, indeed the blur effect will have a corner radius only if the layer of the sourceView has one. Because the sourceView is readonly, it should be set when the registering is made with the method `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:sourceView:`.

As exemple in a collection view with corner radius on its cells, the registering can be made in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. And for security, and as the previewingContext will be checked later, I keep a weak pointer to the previewingContext returned by `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:sourceView:` in the cell itself :

```
if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable) {
    id previewingContext = [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:cell];
    cell.weakPreviewingContext = previewingContext;
}
```

Then in the method `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` of the *UICollectionViewDelegate* protocol I made the unregistering like that :

```
if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:UserInHomeCollectionCell.class]) {
        [self unregisterForPreviewingWithContext:((UserInHomeCollectionCell*)cell).weakPreviewingContext];
    }
}
```

Finally in the method `previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:` of the *UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate* protocol I made the security check like that :

```
UserInHomeCollectionCell *cell = (UserInHomeCollectionCell*)[(UIViewController*)previewingContext view];
NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:UserInHomeCollectionCell.class], @"***** INTERNAL ERROR: Invalid class for retrieved cell %@", cell);
NSAssert([previewingContext isEqual:((UserInHomeCollectionCell*)cell).weakPreviewingContext], @"***** INTERNAL ERROR: Invalid Previewing Context");
```